# laravel 5.3 - multiple rows insert to database table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am trying to add multiple subitems to my eloquent model as arrays but am unable to do so.

**View:**

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <form class="" action="{{route('production.update', $rm->id)}}" method="post">
        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
        {{csrf_field()}}

        <!-- <input type="hidden" name="product_id" id="product_id" class="form-control" value="{{$rm->id}}"> -->

        <div class="form-group{{ ($errors->has('batch_id')) ? $errors->first('title') : '' }}">
          <lable>Batch ID</lable>
          <input type="text" name="batch_id" id="batch_id" class="form-control" value="{{$rm->product_id}}" readonly="">
          {!! $errors->first('wastage','<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group{{ ($errors->has('item_id')) ? $errors->first('title') : '' }}">
          <lable>Item Name</lable>

          <input type="hidden" name="item_id" id="item_id" class="form-control" value="{{$rm->item_id}}" readonly="">

          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$rm->item->item_name}}" readonly="">
          {!! $errors->first('wastage','<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group{{ ($errors->has('rquantity')) ? $errors->first('title') : '' }}">
          <lable>Quantity (Kg)</lable>
          <input type="text" name="rquantity" id="rquantity" class="form-control" value="{{$rm->quantity}}" readonly="">
          {!! $errors->first('wastage','<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group{{ ($errors->has('')) ? $errors->first('title') : '' }}">
          <lable>Packing</lable>

          @foreach($subitem as $sub)

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <input type="checkbox" name="subitem[{{$sub->id}}]['subitem_id']" value="{{$sub->id}}">  {{$sub->subitem_name}}<br><br>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">

              <input type="text" name="subitem[{{$sub->id}}]['qty']" id="qty" class="form-control" placeholder="Entire Qty">
              {!! $errors->first('qty','<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
            </div>


          </div>

          @endforeach


        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $result = Production::findOrFail($id);

    foreach($request->subitem as $key=>$row)
    {
        //print_r($request->subitem);exit;

        $items = new Itempacking;

        $items->batch_id          = $result->product_id;
        $items->item_id           = $result->item_id;
        $items->rquantity         = $result->quantity;
        $items->product_id        = $result->id;

        $items->subitem_id        = $row['subitem_id'];
        $items->qty               = $row['qty'];
        $items->status            = 1;  

        $items->save();

        $items='';
    }
}
```

When I uncomment this line `print_r($request->subitem); exit;` I can see like this:

```
Array ( 
    [3] => Array ( 
        ['subitem_id'] => 3 
        ['qty'] => 2 
    ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
        ['subitem_id'] => 4 
        ['qty'] => 3 
    )
)
```

But when I comment and try to send data to table it is not working. It gives this message

> Undefined index: subitem_id

Comment: If you look, you have an array of subitems, so you'll need to decide the best way you want to put multiple subitems into your tables.

Comment: thank you..can you help me build update function in controller ?

Comment: No. As I said, you'll need to decide how best to add multiple subitems.

Comment: please let me know , my function is wrong..i remove $row['subitem_id'], $row['qty'] and put $items->subitem_id= 1; $items->qty = 2;..then it is work..but $row['subitem_id'] not work

Comment: you will need to use a foreach loop

Comment: do a print_r($row) in foreach and print results, most likely you dont have a "subitem_id" index in your $row

Comment: when i put print_r($row), i can show this result Array ( ['subitem_id'] => 3 ['qty'] => 2 )..it is there

Comment: @lewis4u : i already used foreach loop

Comment: You can extract the subitems to their own model and connect them using a relationship, or save the array as a json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't insert '' for key of array in HTML code.You can print your request to details.

Replace from

```
subitem[{{$sub->id}}]['subitem_id']
subitem[{{$sub->id}}]['qty']
```

to

```
subitem[{{$sub->id}}][subitem_id]
subitem[{{$sub->id}}][qty]
```

Comment: i tried it..but result is same thing..Undefined index: subitem_id

Comment: $arr = array(
  'subitem_id'=>3,
  'qty'=>2,
 );
 print_r($arr);

run this code and compare with your result.

Comment: same results come...but still same error happen..Undefined index: subitem_id